# Disable Slider once used in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, native

I am using rn-vertical-slider and I have to disable it once used i.e once it complete by the user. How can I do that???

Comment: Hello! Can you supply some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library already provides disable props. You need to make following changes in your code.

**Make constructor with isDisable state with default false value**

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
isDisable:false
}

}
```

**Add a function into onChange callback props**

```
_checkMaximunSliderValue=(value)=>{
 If(value==100){ 
this.setState({isDisable:true})
}
}
```

*"Set this.state.isDisable in disable props**

```
<VerticalSlider
  value={1}
  disabled={this.state.isDisable}
  min={0}
  max={100}
  onChange={(value: number) => {
    this._checkMaximunSliderValue(value);
  }}
  onComplete={(value: number) => {
    console.log("COMPLETE", value);
  }}
  width={50}
  height={300}
  step={1}
  borderRadius={5}
  minimumTrackTintColor={"gray"}
  maximumTrackTintColor={"tomato"}
  showBallIndicator
  ballIndicatorColor={"gray"}
  ballIndicatorTextColor={"white"}
/>;
```